# Performance of MySQL SELECT with subqueries and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I'm building a reporting tool for an old application (MySQL 5.6). It uses a single `reports` table, all relevant columns have an index, and the table has about 120'000 rows.

My query is as follows, where the GROUP BY column and the WHERE clauses may change depending on how the user configures the report:

```
SELECT
    nationality AS groupValue,
    ( SELECT COUNT( request_id ) FROM reports WHERE create_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' AND nationality = groupValue ) AS totalRequests,
    ( SELECT SUM(effective_amount) FROM reports WHERE pay_off_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' AND nationality = groupValue ) AS totalSum,
    ( SELECT COUNT( request_id ) FROM reports WHERE pay_off_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' AND current_status = 5 AND nationality = groupValue ) AS totalPaid,
    ( SELECT COUNT( request_id ) FROM reports WHERE failed_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' AND current_status = 3 AND nationality = groupValue ) AS totalRefused,
    ( SELECT COUNT( request_id ) FROM reports WHERE failed_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' AND current_status = 4 AND nationality = groupValue ) AS totalRenounced,
    ( SELECT COUNT( request_id ) FROM reports WHERE failed_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' AND current_status = 2 AND nationality = groupValue ) AS totalInProgress 
FROM
    reports 
GROUP BY
    nationality;
```

The performance is fine with a GROUP BY column of about 40 distinct values, but drops to an unknown time (I gave up waiting) if I choose a column with roughly 200 distinct values (e.g. nationality, see below).

My feeling is that this may have to do with some quadratic complexity due to GROUP BY being used both in the main as well as the subqueries, which I need because the WHERE clauses vary according to their respective SELECT values. But my SQL fu is too long forgotten...

My questions:

1. what is causing the performance decrease?
2. how can this query be improved?

### Update I:

Here is the `reports` table definition (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE `reports` (
  `request_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `failed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_off_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `effective_amount` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_status` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`request_id`,`customer_id`,`employee_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `request_id` (`request_id`),
  KEY `fk_request_id` (`request_id`),
  KEY `fk_employee_id` (`employee_id`),
  KEY `create_date_index` (`create_date`),
  KEY `failed_date_index` (`failed_date`),
  KEY `pay_off_date_index` (`pay_off_date`),
  KEY `nationality_index` (`nationality`(2))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is a query performing well:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | reports | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 118923 | 100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 7 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ref | failed_date_index,nationality_index | nationality_index | 5 | func | 720 | 0.12 | Using where |
| 6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ref | failed_date_index,nationality_index | nationality_index | 5 | func | 720 | 0.12 | Using where |
| 5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ref | failed_date_index,nationality_index | nationality_index | 5 | func | 720 | 0.12 | Using where |
| 4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ALL | pay_off_date_index,nationality_index | NULL | NULL | NULL | 118923 | 1.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x8080) |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ALL | pay_off_date_index,nationality_index | NULL | NULL | NULL | 118923 | 10.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x8080) |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ref | create_date_index,nationality_index | nationality_index | 5 | func | 720 | 2.10 | Using where |

And this is the slow query with nationality:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | reports | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 118923 | 100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 7 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ref | failed_date_index,nationality_index | nationality_index | 5 | func | 720 | 0.12 | Using where |
| 6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ref | failed_date_index,nationality_index | nationality_index | 5 | func | 720 | 0.12 | Using where |
| 5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ref | failed_date_index,nationality_index | nationality_index | 5 | func | 720 | 0.12 | Using where |
| 4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ALL | pay_off_date_index,nationality_index | NULL | NULL | NULL | 118923 | 1.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x8080) |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ALL | pay_off_date_index,nationality_index | NULL | NULL | NULL | 118923 | 10.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x8080) |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | reports | NULL | ref | create_date_index,nationality_index | nationality_index | 5 | func | 720 | 2.10 | Using where |

### Update II

As indicated by commenters below, this is not a kosher usage of GROUP BY. I am unsure exactly how it works, but it does need a `nationality = groupValue` expression in the WHERE clause of each subquery, which seems to cause the aggregations in the subqueries to group for the GROUP BY in  the primary query (explanations welcome!).

I WOULD NOT RECOMMEND using subqueries in this way. In my case, queries often worked, however they also seem to drop of the cliff performance-wise  (or go into an infinite loop?) once the number of distinct values you are grouping by goes high.

Instead, go with CASE as perfectly demonstrated in the answer.

Comment: show output of `show create table reports` and `explain SELECT ...` for the nationality query and for a query that is performing well

Comment: The query is nonsensical I'm afraid. In the absence of any aggregating functions (at the level of the GROUP BY clause) a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate.

Comment: @Strawberry the subqueries operate as aggregations, see the referenced groupValue variable in the subqueries.

Comment: Yes. You can have an aggregating function without a GROUP BY clause. You cannot have a GROUP BY clause without an aggregating function; as is the case here.

Comment: Then why does it execute without error?

Comment: @ysth added the relevant data.

Comment: It can execute without error and be a non sense or incorrect query

Comment: Because sometimes the difference between a bug and a feature is questionable

Comment: If you want DISTINCT results, use the DISTINCT modifier

Comment: Also your reports table is over-simplified.

Comment: @Strawberry @nacho I understand your point, and it is well taken. I was surprised myself that GROUP BY would work in this way. It seems to treat the subqueries as aggregations for the primary query when the subqueries' WHERE clauses have an equal condition on the groupValue variable. In fact the result of the queries are the same as the solution of `@forpas below (when they complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your query, using conditional aggregation and avoid 6 correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT
    nationality AS groupValue,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN create_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' THEN request_id END) AS totalRequests,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pay_off_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' THEN effective_amount END) AS totalSum,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pay_off_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' AND current_status = 5 THEN request_id END) AS totalPaid,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN failed_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' AND current_status = 3 THEN request_id END) AS totalRefused,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN failed_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' AND current_status = 4 THEN request_id END) AS totalRenounced,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN failed_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59' AND current_status = 2 THEN request_id END) AS totalInProgress 
FROM reports 
GROUP BY nationality;
```

Comment: CASE!! That works great, thank you so much!

Comment: More compact (for last column): `SUM(failed_date >= '2020-10-01' AND failed_date < '2022-01-01' AND current_status = 2) AS totalInProgress`